# Client Certificate Authentication and User Enrollment

Tags: openssl, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I'm currently reading the Client X.509 Certificate Authentication and User Enrollment tutorial (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/client-x-509-certificate-authentication-userenrollment/
) and trying to implement it with my current worklight appliation. I'm using Worklight Studio 6.0

However, I'm a bit confused about the authenticationConfig.xml setup. I currently have an adapter authentication working. The first page of my app presents a login page and the adapterChallenge handler will verify the username and password against the database. The following snippet represents the configuration:

```
<customSecurityTest name="AuthRealm">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="AdapterAuthRealm"/>
              <!-- <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SampleAppRealm"/> -->
        </customSecurityTest>  

<realm name="AdapterAuthRealm" loginModule="NonValidatingLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"></parameter>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout"></parameter>
        </realm>

<loginModule name="NonValidatingLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
```

I'm not sure how to use the following snippet of the tutorial to tie into my setup. Does my security test become step 2 or 3? Do I simply add these under my security test (AuthRealm)?

```
        <customSecurityTest name="customx509Tests">
                    <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
                    <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
                    <test realm="wl_userCertificateAuthRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
                    <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
                </customSecurityTest>

            <realm name="wl_userCertificateAuthRealm" loginModule="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">


    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateAuthenticator</className>
                    <parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="SampleAppRealm" />
                    <parameter name="pki-bridge-class" value="com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateEmbeddedPKI" />
                    <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-file-path" value="/path/to/certificates/directory/signingca/signing_ca.p12"/> 
                    <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-password" value="passSigningP12" />
                </realm>

<loginModule name="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: First thing first - don't try to implement a 6.3 tutorial in 6.0. Upgrade.

Comment: I have upgraded to worklight studio 6.3 as requested.

Comment: Are there any other suggestions on how to configure the secuirty aspect?

Comment: What is *"Does my security test become step 2 or 3"*? You should list them with the question.

Comment: I meant step as in the xml attribute which I have in te snippet above. isInternalUserID="true" step="1". I want to know how to order it properly so that I preserve my setup and incorporate the tests of the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user authentication feature is it's own separate security realm.   It allows you to specify a dependent user auth realm that is used when an x509 certificate is not provided by the client. The dependent realm is basically used to enroll the device/user/app into your PKI.  The dependent realm can be any security realm you choose.

To specify your security realm as the dependent realm, change the following line:

```
<parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="SampleAppRealm" />
```

to:

```
<parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="AdapterAuthRealm" />
```

Was this your question?

FYI, you can read up more on the feature at: 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_user_CA.html

and the server side PKI configuration for more details:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_user_CA_PKIBridge.html

Comment: Thank you lizet. This answers it perfectly! I have ticked your answer as green.